# How to set a variable and check it for null both in the "case when" conditions SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem with this piece of code.

I need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT
...
    CASE   
        WHEN (@UserID = (SELECT TOP 1 UserPk FROM Users WHERE Name= 'JoeDoe')) IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END
```

I need set `@UserID` for some other next steps and at the same time need to check `(SELECT TOP 1 UserPk FROM Users WHERE Name = 'JoeDoe')` for null.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you provide some additional context? Since `case` is not a statement it needs to be part of something else. A `select` statement can either return values or set variables, but not both. An `update` statement does allow setting variables and updating rows.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT UserPk FROM Users WHERE Name= 'JoeDoe')
    SET @UserID = 0;
ELSE
    SET @UserID = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Wouter. But this could set UserID to 0 or 1, but point of code above, is Set UserID to real userPk.

Comment: That *isn't* what the code you supplied us in your question does, @JoeOwlDoes .

Comment: oh ok, then just do this: SELECT @UserID  = ISNULL(MAX(UserPk),0) FROM Users WHERE Name= 'JoeDoe'

Comment: Yea, maybe, i finish that, i think this syntax cant be write by SQL

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just an `ISNULL`?

```
SET @UserID = ISNULL(SELECT UserPk FROM Users WHERE Name= 'JoeDoe'),0);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this does not work in this situation. I spoke with others and looks like, this special case SQL does not support.

Comment: I meant WHEN (@UserID = (SELECT TOP 1 UserPk FROM Users WHERE Name= 'JoeDoe')) IS NULL

Comment: What special case SQL? The above works in every supported version of SQL Server, and would even work in unsupported versions, @JoeOwlDoes .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT;

SET @UserId = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Name= 'JoeDoe')
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0
               END);
```

I'm not sure why you are calling this column `@UserId`.  It appears to be a flag on the presence of the name.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT
SET @UserID = ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM Users WHERE Name= 'JoeDoe'), 0)

Print @UserID
```